# Как найти "себе" this в статическом векторе класса в C++?

Tags: c++, классы, указатели, vector, операторы

Есть класс "Camera". В нем есть статический список всех созданных камер:

`private:static std::vector<Camera> cameras;`

В конструкторе этого класса кладу "себя"(this) в этот список так:

```
Camera::cameras.push_back(*this);
```

Хочу удалить "себя" из этого списка в деструкторе. Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
cameras.erase(std::find(cameras.begin(), cameras.end(), *this));
```

Выдает ошибку компиляции:

```
Ошибка  C2678   бинарный "==": не найден оператор, принимающий левый операнд типа "Camera" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)
```

Что я делаю не правильно?
Я думаю нужно переопределить оператор == для сравнения двух камер. Но в этом ли проблема?

Comment: А вы кладите в вектор указатель, а не объект. `std::vector<Camera*>` и `.push_back(this);`

Comment: @gil9red, Да так делал до этого но где-то в дебрях stackoverflow вычитал что на производительность  это особо не влияет(у меня же не тысячи камер в сцене), и по что по возможности нужно использовать не указатели а просто сами объекты. А вы как храните в основном?

Comment: Да по разному, зависит от ситуации. Смотрите, если указатели поместите, вектор сравнит по указателям, если как объекты, тогда создайте оператор `==`, чтобы вектор мог сравнить как объекты.

Comment: Т.е. дело всё таки в операторе "==". Спасибо! Это и был ответ!!

Comment: добавляя в вектор объекты по значению, туда заноситься его копия. Вполне возможно, что когда будете удалять, то ничего с вектора не удалиться (все зависит от того, как будет написан оператор ==)

Comment: Не стал парить себе мозг копиями, лучше буду хранить указатели) Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @gil9red, Вы бы вынесли это в ответ, чтобы закрыть вопрос.

Comment: А лучше не указатели хранить в векторе, а shared_ptr.

Comment: @gil9red, я уже видел эту штуку, чуть позже к этому приду, сначала хотя бы просто на указателях и ссылках натаскаюсь до конца.

Comment: вы промахнулись с ответом ) и ответ уже дан )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вот здесь

```
Camera::cameras.push_back(*this);
```

вы вносите в вектор **копию** своего объекта. При удалении вектор пытается сравнивать **объекты**, а не указатели. Для этого ему нужен оператор сравнивания.

Самое разумное - не копировать свои камеры, копировать адреса. Т.е. использовать

```
static std::vector<Camera*> cameras;
```

При этом не будут создаваться лишние сущности, что уже хорошо.

Если вам все-таки необходимо хранить копии, то второй вариант - определить оператор сравнивания, а третий - использовать `find_if` с соответствующим предикатом (вплоть до лямбды).

Но передача адреса, по-моему, наиболее эффективное решение.

Answer (score 4):

Дополню @Harry.

Если не хотите, что бы какой-то зловред положил туда `nullptr`, можно организовать и вектор "ссылок":

```
private:static std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Camera>> cameras;
```

И ложить туда ссылку на класс:

```
Camera::cameras.push_back(std::ref(*this));
```

Ну а поиск нужного элемента можно произвести по его адресу:

```
cameras.erase(std::find_if(cameras.begin(), cameras.end(), [this](std::reference_wrapper<Camera> wrapper) {
  return &wrapper.get() == this;
}));
```

Гадость положить туда всё ещё можно, но уже будет сложнее :)